# ionic slider pager position to bottom right

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have a ionic slider in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/AjgEB). How could i position the pager to the bottom right? I try to use following code but not working.

```
.slider-pager {
        right: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: .slider .slider-pager {text-align: right;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.slider .slider-pager {
   text-align: right;
}
```

will work as `span` has `inline-block` property

http://codepen.io/victorfdes/pen/qZvBmw